# How to expose QMap to QML using QDeclarative

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qmap

How can I expose QMap from C++ to QML?
Using QList I can use QDeclarativeListProperty.

Answer (score 6):

You could convert or change it into a QVariantMap. In QML you can use the QVariantMap instance as a normal Javascript object.

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariantMap getIntMap() {
        QVariantMap rval;
        foreach (QString key, m_intMap.keys()) {
            // int has an implicit conversion to QVariant
            rval[key] = m_intMap[key]; 
        }
        return rval;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariantMap getObjMap() {
        QVariantMap rval;
        foreach (QString key, m_objMap.keys()) {
            // TODO: make sure all QObject subclasses are exported to QML
            rval[key] = QVariant::fromValue<QObject*>(m_objMap[key]); 
        }
        return rval;
    }

private:
    QMap<QString, int> m_intMap;
    QMap<QString, QObject*> m_objMap;
}
```